# Dynamic parameter with git in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there some way to get the **git parameter** dynamically in jenkins?

```
https://mygitaddressnothere:8888/$mygit.git
```

Suposing that I am using the variable mygit.

Comment: Give more details. What is the scenario you want to implement? You can put a variable in the Git URL field and it will work.

Comment: Hi, I just realize now, how to use this variable.

Comment: https://mygitaddressnothere:8888/${mygit}.git

Comment: Put it as an official answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After time, I found out how to use the parameter.

```
https://mygitaddressnothere:8888/${mygit}.git
```

instead of:

```
http://mygitaddressnothere:8888/$mygit.git
```